# Sybase 12.5 on Windows 7

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I will be working on a project that uses Sybase 12.5 for the database. I cannot really find anything interesting on the internet about this version of the SGBD.

I was so far able to install a client (Squirrel) on my Windows 7 machine, but I am now still looking for a way to run Sybase 12.5 on the same machine.

Would you please know where I can download Sybase 12.5 for free? Would it still work if I install Sybase ASE 15.5 on my machine?

Thank you,
Regards

Comment: I've run 12.5 on Vista, no reason to think it wouldn't work on 7 as well.  As far as places to download 12.5, I am not aware of any.  Even with a SAP support contract, I don't know if it's available.  15.5 would work, just read the 'What's new' sections of the documentation for 15 & 15.5 to make sure you are not using any features that are not available in 12.5.

Comment: I absolutely need to work on 12.5. A colleague of mine has a VM with this version installed. I shall try that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 12.5 is quite old and out of support.  Basically,  no need to run such an old version.  You can even run 15.7 and 16.x in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase 12.5 has been out of support for a number of years. The only way I can imagine you being able to download Sybase ASE 12.5 is with a support contract that has been extended to cover that version.

Later Sybase ASE versions generally offer excellent backwards compatibility with the older versions provided you keep away from the new functionality.

Consider the risks associated with running older software that is no longer supported by the vendor. You may want to approach the organisation and find out their migration strategy.